# Why is it not possible to implicitly convert char** to const char **

Tags: c++, casting, char

I have a code which does more or less:

```
bar(const char**)
{
// stuff
}

foo(char** arr)
{
  bar(arr);
}
```

The compiler notifies me that i am doing an `invalid conversion from ‘char**’ to ‘const char**’`. While I know what it means, I fail to understand why is it not allowed. It is perfectly ok to pass `char*` where `const char*` is needed.

Comment: Don't you have an extra `*` in the function signature?

Comment: Do you mean... `bar(const char**)` ?

Comment: I mean, in the function signature of `bar()` you have `const char***`, there's 3 asterisks. Didn't you mean to have two perhaps?

Comment: It's nothing to do with the `const`, it's the extra `*` as Andy Prowl suggested.

Comment: @SuvP: Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: Yeah, the signature was wrong, sorry :(

Comment: One of the many duplicates. See [comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 11.10 - Why can't I pass a char ** to a function which expects a const char **?](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html).

Comment: While I agree that the problem is the same as in the submitted duplicate, I would suggest leaving the question and posting an answer. I did not manage to find the resolution to my problem in google and I believe that the question can help other people

Comment: @PeteBecker you edited the question - but the original was better. Not only can't you implicitly convert char** to const char**, you can't do it explicitly in C++. Please revert.

Comment: @Dariusz - you can force the conversion with a `const_cast`.

Comment: @Dariusz: well you can do it explicitly (e.g. `const_cast`), and Pete knows a bit about what you can do, being the one who penned the current standard. u now. so -- i was too tired to notice when i edited the title, but Pete fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because if it was allowed then you could inadvertently change something that was declared `const`.

here's a concrete abuse example, if the rules allowed this:

```
char const* s = "a literal, very const";

bar(const char** pp )
{
    *pp = s;
}

foo(char** arr)
{
  bar(arr);
  char* unconsted_s = *arr;
  unconsted_s[0] = 'X';
}
```

This is also a [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/constptrptr-conversion.html). It’s often a good idea to check the FAQ (or just google) before asking.

Answer (score 0):

It can lead to similar scenario if its allowed.

```
void foo(int** arr)
{
    /*Can freely modify value at location pointed by a*/
   **arr = 6;
}


int main()
{
 /*Pointer to constant*/
 int i = 5;

 const int* a =&a;

 /*Not a pointer to constant*/
 int** aa= &a;

 foo(aa);

return 0;
}
```